# How do I remind users to pick an avatar?

Tags: 7, media

I use the Avatar Selection Module to provide a list avatars my users can choose from. I don't want to make choosing an avatar required, but I'd like to have a persistent reminder for users who have not picked an avatar for themselves.

How can I identify users who have NOT chosen an avatar and use Context (or something else) to conditionally display a message in a block like, "Hey you haven't chosen an avatar yet. GO HERE (User Form) to choose one."?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

[Profile Complete Percent](https://drupal.org/project/pcp) helps to guilt users into filling their profile details. This isn't avatar specific, but you can configure the PCP block to only use a single field for its percentage calculation.

Answer (score 1):

### The following only works if you created your own image field. Ex: I added an image field called avatar to my users fields and disabled the default picture field over at `/admin/config/people/accounts`

Going off memory here.

You can do this using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)

Add a new rule:

React on event >> After user has logged in

Add Condition >> Data is Empty >> account:field-avatar

Action >> [under system] Show message >> Hello [account:name] you have not selected an avatar yet, please go `<a href="/user/[account:nid]/edit">here</a>` to add an avatar. >>

Repeat message: True.

---

### If you're using the Drupal default picture, take a look at the answer to this:

### [How to check with Rules if users have a custom picture](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/101220/how-to-check-with-rules-if-users-have-a-custom-picture)

Comment: The  fields for "account:field-avatar" and "account:picture" don't appear on my list of Data Selectors. When I try to type them in I get the message, "Data selector account:picture for parameter data is invalid." What am I missing?

Comment: @AaronThain Sorry, since I use my custom picture field, I assumed the account:picture field would be available. To my shock and disbelief it is not. Funny how it is available for sending e-mail but not for stuff like this... Anyways, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Interesting (tough) case to get it to work with the Rules module in case you use the default picture. It was a bit too challenging to NOT add another answer to that http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/101220 (which does not require a custom module ...).